How to click on an element in android where clickable attribute is false
I am new to mobile automation. I am trying to click on an element where the displayed attribute is true, but the other attributes are false.
{"key":"checkable","value":"false","name":"checkable"},{"key":"checked","value":"false","name":"checked"},{"key":"clickable","value":"false","name":"clickable"},{"key":"enabled","value":"true","name":"enabled"},{"key":"focusable","value":"false","name":"focusable"},{"key":"focused","value":"false","name":"focused"},{"key":"long-clickable","value":"false","name":"long-clickable"},{"key":"password","value":"false","name":"password"},{"key":"scrollable","value":"false","name":"scrollable"},{"key":"selected","value":"false","name":"selected"},{"key":"bounds","value":"[0,132][147,265]","name":"bounds"},{"key":"displayed","value":"true","name":"displayed"},{"key":"hint","value":"","name":"hint"}]
I have tried numerous solutions like Click on elements using coordinates, Tapactions etc. But none of them seems to be working. Also the strange part is, it works on some of the devices.
I am using Pixel 8 with UpsideDownCake(Android 14)
Can anyone please help on this?

From  logs it seems clicking on the coordinates. but in the ui screen i am not able to see the changes. Am I missing something?
[503e8916][AndroidUiautomator2Driver@8c31] Proxying [POST /actions] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8203/session/0f519e86-a560-4844-b640-4794bd07bfb2/actions] with body: {"actions":[{"id":"finger1","type":"pointer","parameters":{"pointerType":"touch"},"actions":[{"duration":0,"type":"pause"},{"duration":0,"x":77,"y":276,"type":"pointerMove","origin":"viewport"},{"button":0,"type":"pointerDown"},{"button":0,"type":"pointerUp"}]}]}
[503e8916][AndroidUiautomator2Driver@8c31]
